# DNN5: all modules have disappeared

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, admin, dotnetnuke-5

Yesterday we had a 100 modules, now there is only 1 module in the dropdown list that Admin can add to the page.
There is no HTML module, no iframe module, no nothing. The dropdown is blank (?)

screenshot of admin view:
http://s11.postimg.org/ii397az9v/modules_blank.png

I have no idea how this happened. All i did was try to get rid of a module for 1 specific portal, i went to  Host > Extensions > geoRedirect > Edit > unassign that 1 module from1 specific portal and clicked update.

And now the "add new module" dropdown is blank, on all our portals. I never edited the settings for html or other modules. How can i restore all the modules in the module list?

Note: our existing sites show the existing modules that were added to pages, but in the dropdown there is none. Nothing can be added.

Comment: update: 
it appears the modules have become unassigned. none are deleted but they need to be reassigned under Host > Ext-s to reappear in the Admin toolbar. Is it possible to assigned them all at once rather than one module at a time?

Comment: Not possible through the UI, you would have to do it in the database